# C++ what happens when incrementing a char *

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, strlen

Say I have the following code:

```
void incrementPointer( const char *x) {

    char *localVar = new char;
    char *localVarPtr = localVar;
    while(*xPtr != '\0') {
        xPtr++;
        localVarPtr++;
    }
}
```

Let's say that x is pointing to some null-terminated word. After the execution of the while loop, is the localVarPtr pointing to a location that has not been allocated for localVar? For instance, if I declare some other variable in this function, and then set all bytes between localVar and localVarPtr to the character 'c', would this potentially overwrite the value of the other variable?

My other question is if this is considered bad practice (i.e. potentially overwriting variables or causing undefined behavior), what would be the way to allocate enough space for localVar if x is pointing to a word who's size is **unlimited**? The size of x may be larger than an unsigned integer, and thus I would not be able to use the size in the initialization of localVar.

Comment: Where can I buy one of those computers with unlimited memory? I didn't get one for Christmas :-(

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say that x is pointing to some null-terminated word. After the execution of the while loop, is the localVarPtr pointing to a location that has not been allocated for localVar?

That depends entirely on the length of x - If for example x contains only the null-terminator then no, the value of localVarPtr points to the beginning of the region allocated by new.

> For instance, if I declare some other variable in this function, and then set all bytes between localVar and localVarPtr to the character 'c', would this potentially overwrite the value of the other variable?

You're not mutating the memory stored in any of the addresses so no, an overwrite would not occur. If your localVarPtr points to the region at say address 0x8000 and you then modify 0x8010, assuming that 0x0810 is a "local variable" then yes, its contents would be changed. This is the wild west, any valid (or sometimes invalid) address that is dereferenced and assigned to will change or signal.

> My other question is if this is considered bad practice (i.e. potentially overwriting variables or causing undefined behavior),

Yes, typically pointing to or modifying undefined memory is bad practice. A pointer to a local variable, intentionally set that way however, is perfectly fine. Undefined behavior is always bad practice.

> what would be the way to allocate enough space for localVar if x is pointing to a word who's size is unlimited? The size of x may be larger than an unsigned integer, and thus I would not be able to use the size in the initialization of localVar.

As Mat denoted, there is no such way to have an "unlimited" length string. If you need to allocate space to match the size of the string for x, you'll have to simply know the size either by calling a function to determine its length, or passing it in to this function. Once you know the size, you can use new to allocate for it.